# Render texture in fullscreen centered and with the right ratio in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

Im loading a bitmap into the renderer class and I want to render the texture centered in the screen with the right ratio and as big as it can be

The vertices and texture data:

private final float[] mVerticesData =
    { 
            -1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 0
            0.0f, 0.0f, // TexCoord 0
            -1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 1
            0.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 1
            1f, -1f, 0.0f, // Position 2
            1.0f, 1.0f, // TexCoord 2
            1f, 1f, 0.0f, // Position 3
            1.0f, 0.0f // TexCoord 3
    };

```
private final short[] mIndicesData =
{ 
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 
};
```

And the draw method :

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
    {

```
    // Set the viewport
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height);

    // Clear the color buffer
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use the program object
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

    // Load the vertex position
    mVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, 
                                   false, 
                                   5 * 4, mVertices );
    // Load the texture coordinate
    mVertices.position(3);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                                   false, 
                                   5 * 4, 
                                   mVertices );

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mPositionLoc );
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

    // Bind the texture
    GLES20.glActiveTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId );

    // Set the sampler texture unit to 0
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0 );

    GLES20.glDrawElements ( GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices );
}
```

Right now Im setting the viewport with the bitmap dimensions(not working). How should I calculate the viewport dimensions for the texture to fit the screen keeping the ratio?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use ModelViewPrjoection matrix. Look at this source
http://code.google.com/p/android-opengles-samples-for-vikulov-blogspot-com/source/browse/trunk/OpenglTemplate/src/com/vikulov/opengl/MyGLRenderer.java